# Need help deactivate and activating multiple gameobjects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to activate one game object at a time on button press but end up not being able too activate any

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class MutliCamScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject cam1;
    public GameObject cam2;
    public GameObject cam3;
    public GameObject cam4;
    public GameObject cam5;
    public GameObject cam6;
    public GameObject cam7;
    public GameObject cam8;
 
    public void switchcam(int x) {
        deactivateall();
        if (x == 1)
        {
            cam1.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (x == 2){
            cam2.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (x == 3){
            cam3.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (x == 4){
            cam4.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (x == 5){
            cam5.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (x == 6){
            cam6.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (x == 7){
            cam7.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (x == 8){
            cam8.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
 
    public void deactivateall() {
        cam1.SetActive(false);
        cam2.SetActive(false);
        cam3.SetActive(false);
        cam5.SetActive(false);
        cam6.SetActive(false);
        cam7.SetActive(false);
        cam8.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it should work. Are all the camera GameObjects correctly assigned in the inspector? Try putting a debug message inside the function to make sure the button is successfully calling it.

Comment: Oh, deactivateall() is missing cam4 though.

Answer (score 0):

You have no Input, this script won't detect what you are pressing I'm warning you now this code it's not perfect the deactivateall() is reapeated but should do the trick so you can test it

```
 void Update()
{
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha1))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam1.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha2))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam2.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha3))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam3.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha4))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam4.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha5))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam5.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha6))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam6.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha7))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam7.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha8))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam8.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

The full code is this

```
 public GameObject cam1;
public GameObject cam2;
public GameObject cam3;
public GameObject cam4;
public GameObject cam5;
public GameObject cam6;
public GameObject cam7;
public GameObject cam8;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha1))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam1.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha2))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam2.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha3))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam3.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha4))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam4.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha5))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam5.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha6))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam6.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha7))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam7.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha8))
    {
        deactivateall();
        cam8.SetActive(true);
    }
}


public void deactivateall()
{
    cam1.SetActive(false);
    cam2.SetActive(false);
    cam3.SetActive(false);
    cam4.SetActive(false);
    cam5.SetActive(false);
    cam6.SetActive(false);
    cam7.SetActive(false);
    cam8.SetActive(false);
}
```